# Remove transparent pixels from an imported image in Flash Professional

Tags: animation, transparency

I'm using Adobe Flash Professional and using a sprite my friend drew for me. It has a transparent background and when I import it into flash and break it up, it recognizes the background. This is problematic as I want to try to attach bones to it for easier animating.

Is there a way to delete these transparent pixels? The lasso tool is too hard to accurately use to delete the pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to open the sprite in Illustrator first and use the Trace function to convert the sprite to a vector graphic. Set the Trace function to “ignore white” to trace only the foreground. Then save the vector sprite and import it into Flash and you will likely get much better results throughout the rest of your work.

Comment: Is there another way without Illustrator? Because my illustrator stopped working and I don't have time to redownload and install

Comment: Attaching bones is still hard as when I trace it it splits it so much